# Compute the tortuosity of a polyline

Tags: polyline

I have series of (x, y) coordinates, if joined this represent a polyline. This polyline is a geographic track.

All that I need is to get the polyline tortuosity. It should be usefull a sort of percentage. E.g. The path has x% tortuosity.

Comment: How is the title of your question related to the body? What "futures" do you want to extract?

Comment: anyway i edited the title so that it reflects the content of the post.

Comment: Sorry I edited body and forget to edit subject :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, it all depends on how you define tortuosity. there is a [wikipedia article regarding tortuosity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tortuosity), which may shed some light on the subject.

an interesting sentence in the article tells us that: `"roughness (or tortuosity) could be measured by relative change of curvature"`. that makes a good starting point.

your polyline is made of adjacent line segments. you can compute the angle between each adjacent line segment. using this information you can get a good idea of tortuosity for your polyline. for example, let `seg(n)` be the line segment between point `n` and point `n+1`:

```
tortuosity = sum(abs(angle(seg(n), seg(n+1))) for n in 1 to number of segment)
```

*(computing the angle between 2 line segments is left as an exercise, but does not require a degree in mathematics)*

the above measure is not scaled: the more points you have, the higher the value might be. you can easily scale this result according to the number of line segments you have:

```
unit_tortuosity = tortuosity / (n * pi)
```

*(the maximum angle between 2 line segments is `pi`, adjust your `angle()` function so that it returns a result between `0` and `pi`. so your tortuosity would be at most `n*pi`, hence the above scaling factor which allows to have a value between `0` and `1` with `0` representing a perfectly straight polyline)*

Comment: Yes, I have reading articles but I want mantain the question as open as I can ;)
What do you think about (total track lenght)/(straight distance among start and end point)?

Comment: @Mariano: `(total track lenght)/(straight distance among start and end point)` seems to be a gross estimation, and may give surprising results in some cases. for example: imagine a track of someone going straight ahead, then coming back on its path to end at its starting point. it will have the same result as someone performing zig-zags for going somewhere, although the first track is straight but not the second.

Comment: Yes, you've right, I have said a a wrong thing.
I haven't understand why you consider pi/2 (90 degrees) as maximum.

Comment: @Mariano: oops, my bad. i was really meaning `pi` (180 deg) ! (edited the answer...)

Comment: I've supposed, matter of fact seems weird pi/2. It's ok now! Thank you a lot! :)

Comment: In this way, if two segments, are perfectly straight they realizes a 180 degrees angle. And so 180/(2*180)=0.5, a 50% of tortuosity for a polyline perfectly straight? Where is the mistake?

Comment: remember that i am talking of segments for which the direction matters. if 2 segments have an angle of 180 degrees, they are going in opposite direction, so yes, that's (a bit) tortuous. two segments going in the same direction defines a real straight line and have a tortuosity of 0.